# store drop down options in array, PHP

Tags: php, html, select

I am stuck on an issue in PHP. I have a DropDown and for it I am using the HTML `<select />` tag in PHP. I want a button named `Add`, and as user clicks on it, the selected option in the DropDown gets added to an array.

This is my code of select tag

```
echo "<tr><td><select name='stuid'>";
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($analysis);$i++)
    {
  echo "<option value={$analysis[$i]}>{$analysis[$i]}</option>";
  }

echo "</select >";
```

This analysis array hold some values that I am reading from a file.

Comment: Can you please describe more about the thing you want to do? Like what array are you trying to add the selected option to?

Comment: You need to supply more information and try to be more clear on the problem. I just think this question isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that, you didn't say what is happening and what is expected to happen. But there's something that you need to change with the code:

```
echo "<tr><td><select name='stuid'>";
for($i=0; $i < count($analysis); $i++)
{
  echo "<option value={$analysis[$i]}>{$analysis[$i]}</option>";
}
echo "</select >";
```

You can use `count()` instead of `sizeof()` for an array. BTW, both are same.

Also, when you say that, when a user clicks on a button, an option should be added, then you need to use JavaScript for that, and not PHP, as PHP is a server side thing.

My suggestion to your code is, using JavaScript, you can fetch the value from something, say a textbox, and then add it to the `select`. Your code might look this way:

```
<input type="text" id="newoption" />
<input type="button" value="Add"
       onclick="document.getElementById('items').add(document.getElementById('newoption').value);" />
<select id="items">
  ...
</select>
```

Comment: You can even use `new Option()`.